# Ctrl+Space overwrite method with the one selected

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I do to overwrite a method with the one i just selected?
For example:

First I type

```
SomeClass.someMethod():
```

but then, I reminded that the method was another one, and the cursor was after the word some and before Method, when I press Ctrl+Space again, it shows up some methods, when i hit enter, my method now is something like this:

```
SomeClass.someOneElsesMethod()someMethod();
```

How do I do to when I press Ctrl+Space, and select a method it just overwrites?
I used to work like this but can't remember how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Menu: `Window -> Preferences`, select: `Java -> Editor -> Content Assist`

In the resulting screen, find `Insertion` and set the selection to `Completion overwrites`.